# having trouble using delegates in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

With the use of delegates, I want number 5 from IEnumerable items to print to the screen by using the following code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using extended;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> cities = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            IEnumerable<int> query = cities.StartsWith(hello);

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int hello(int x)
        {
        return x > 4 ? x : 0;
        }
    }
}
namespace extended
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, inputdelegate<T> predicate)
        {
            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                if (item.Equals(predicate))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
        public delegate int inputdelegate<T>(T input);
    }
}
```

code compiles without any error but displays no output to the screen. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: `if (item.Equals(predicate))` is always false. What was your intention?

Comment: @AlexD on number 5 in {1,2,3,4,5} predicate = 5 and in `foreach (var item in input)` when loop iterates to item 5 , `(item.Equals(predicate))` should return true?

Comment: @RehanKhan I've provided some fixes to your source code in an answer below that produces what you are looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: I guess that predicate should be `bool`, return `true` for value `5`, and then be invoked as `if(predicate(item)){yield return item;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking your predicate.  Also, inputdelegate should probably have a return type of T.  Change your code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using extended;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> cities = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            IEnumerable<int> query = cities.StartsWith(hello);

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int hello(int x)
        {
        return x > 4 ? x : 0;
        }
    }
}
namespace extended
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, inputdelegate<T> predicate)
        {
            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                if (item.Equals(predicate(item)))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
        public delegate T inputdelegate<T>(T input);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Based on comments from AlexD, you should consider changing your test to:

```
if (predicate(item))
```

and updating your delegate to:

```
public delegate bool inputdelegate<T>(T input);
```

and updating your Hello function to:

```
static bool hello(int x)
{
    return x > 4;
}
```

Comment: _"inputdelegate should probably have a return type of T"_ If it is a predicate, should not it return `bool`?

Comment: @Tyree Jackson correct. Missed to pass the parameter for predicate :) Thanks alot.

Comment: The author is not really using a predicate in the LINQ sense of the term.  He created a custom delegate to write functions return the a value of the same type as the parameter to the delegate.  I agree, that a bool return would be better, but ultimately, that is up to the author.

Comment: I dont know much in programming but what I understand so far about delegates return type is it really depends upon your requirement. Delegates can return any type depending on your need. This is going off the topic, back to topic: when I was not passing parameter to predicate delegate, why was it not throwing any errors on compile or runtime?

Comment: @RehanKhan You were not getting a compile time error because .Equals accepts arguments of type System.Object.  All delegate derive from System.Object, so the delegate itself was a valid test which returned false.  In effect you were comparing ((object) 1) == ((object) delegate(hello)) which is false.

Comment: @TyreeJackson Got it. Thanks for all the help.